# Why do I keep getting INVALID_RESOURCE_ID error in production when trying to set up PayPal payment?

Tags: javascript, web, paypal, payment, paypal-rest-sdk

I want to set up an one-time PayPal payment. I am calling `<script data-page-type="checkout" src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id={my client id}&currency=CZK&commit=true&intent=capture&debug=true"></script>` from HTML to get the button to show.

I then set it up in the client-side javascript like this

```
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return fetch('/.netlify/functions/transactionProcessor?orderAction=create', {
                method: 'post',
            }).then(function(functionResponse) {
                console.log("order created");
                return functionResponse.json();
            }).then(function(functionResponseJson) {
                return functionResponseJson.id;
            });
        },
```

When the user clicks the button, createOrder is called. CreateOrder then calls this server-side code

```
async function createOrder(client) {
    // Call PayPal to set up a transaction.
    const request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();
    request.prefer('return=minimal');
    request.requestBody({
        intent: 'CAPTURE',
        purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
                currency_code: 'CZK',
                value: '69.99'
            }
        }]
    });
    
    const order = await client.execute(request);
    console.log('order successfuly created');

    // Return a successful serverResponse to the client with the order ID.
    return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify({ serverResponse: order, id: 
    order.result.id }) }
}
```

That returns absolutely fine. The client-side code then handles it by returning it in it's createOrder method - and here the error occurs.

RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND (https://justpaste.it/resource_not_found_paypal_err)

INVALID_RESOURCE_ID (https://justpaste.it/invalid_resource_id_err)

I have absolutely no idea why it happens and I've been trying to fix it for days already. It WORKS IN SANDBOX.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be doing a REST API capture request from the client side. This API call to PayPal should only be executed from a server.

As for why it is erroring with an invalid profile ID in live but not sandbox, it's possible you neglected to update the clientID+secret in said client side code. However, as mentioned, the secret (and the auth token you get with it) should never be used from the client side. It is for server-side API calls only.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was accidentally using sandbox environment on the server. The logic was `process.env.SANDBOX ? sandboxEnv : liveEnv`, but the process.env variable doesn't work for some reason (Netlify + Netlify dev). I replaced it with local `const sandbox = false`.

Can't believe I spent so much time on this. I'd never find this if I didn't fiddle with it so stupidly much.